# Scheduling - Logic

Tags: logic

Here's the scenario:

A Enterprise have 6 offices across the state. Each city have their own quantity of employees and capacity of having visitors.
During 24 weeks the Company wants that all of its employees get to know the other offices.
The problem relies on city1 with the most number of employees that can leave only 5 per week. The other cities will leave only one per week.

$6$ cities total

- city1 = $31$ persons
- city2 = $2$ persons $+ 1$ free spot
- city3 = $3$ persons $+ 1$ free spot
- city4 = $4$ persons
- city5 = $3$ persons $+ 1$ free spot
- city6 = $2$ persons $+ 1$ free spot

Rules:

1. Each person has to visit all others cities (Meaning 5 cities total)
2. Only $1$ person leaves from each city at the time - Except city1 $\to$ 5
3. Each city can accept the number of people that leaves + free spot
4. All visitations has to occur in $24$ weeks - But only $1$ caster per week

I tried something like this:

```
loop 24 weeks
    loop (total person to visit (10))
        loop cities
            -> has visited? No -> visit | Yes -> Next city
            -> All visited? Next person
```

But I got $41$ weeks. Almost the double asked.
Is it possible to make in the terms requested?

Comment: You said there are 6 cities total, and then listed five cities. Where is the missing one? (Of course I'm assuming this has nothing to do with Atlantis)

Comment: lol - Fixed, thx.

Comment: What does "1 caster per week" mean?

Comment: Well, only once a week the visitions will occour. Meaning only a group of 10 people total per week.

Comment: There is a lot of information missing.  Does each person start in a different city or do they all start in city 1?  What does Except city$ 1 \to 5$ mean?  What is a caster?  There should be some introductory text that describes the problem, then the data you give for specifics.

Comment: Sorry. Each person starts at their own city. Example: the 2 persons of city2 starts at city2 and has to visit all other 5 cities. "Except city1 -> 5" means that only from city1 can leave 5 person at the time. All others can only leave one.

Comment: Can you please share your 41-week schedule?

Comment: Thanks for the bounty.  I am still interested in seeing your 41-week schedule.

Comment: @RobPratt well, i was trying to achieve the result using programming. My final version is resulting 39weeks but i may have twisted the rules a little bit to present different approaches to the requester. I didn't control source versions in this case, so i only have the final result in microsoft excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it cannot be done in 24 weeks or even 41 weeks.  Here is a schedule that takes 43 weeks:
[image]

Here's a schedule that takes 42 weeks and tries to minimize the number of moves from one city to another:
[image]

And here's a schedule that takes 42 weeks and tries to minimize the number of weeks away from home:
[image]